# MySql compare row values and pick one if the condition statisfied

Tags: mysql, compare

I am trying to write a sql logic which will compare rows for a user and based on a condition it will pick one.

For eg.

```html
+-------+------+--+
| UseId | Code |  |
+-------+------+--+
|     1 | A    |  |
|     2 | B    |  |
|     3 | C    |  |
|     4 | D    |  |
|     4 | E    |  |
|     5 | F    |  |
|     5 | G    |  |
+-------+------+--+
```

The output im trying to get is, if a user has 2 records compare the code like if code =D and code=E for user 4, then retain row with code E
for user 5 , if Code=F and Code=G then retain row with code F

so the output should look like

```html
+-------+------+--+
| UseId | Code |  |
+-------+------+--+
|     1 | A    |  |
|     2 | B    |  |
|     3 | C    |  |
|     4 | E    |  |
|     5 | F    |  |
|       |      |  |
+-------+------+--+
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain the logic behind your choice of the code to retain. Why the greater code (`'E > 'D'`) for one user and the lesser code for the other?

Comment: There are pre-defined rules that if a user is part of 2 insurance groups, then based on conditions we have to pick one. For Instance, if a patient has Medicare and commercial insurance then pick Medicare. If patient has Medicaid & commercial insurance then pick Commercial.